# Button click using vba is throwing error

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I need to click a button in a webpage but there are multiple elements with the same properties in the web page and my code is displaying an error message.

In trail and error base I have tried to click each and every element one by one even I am unable to get the required stuff.

Please find my code below

```
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With objIE
.Visible = True
.navigate "http://www.cargurus.com/"


Do While .busy Or _
.readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Loop

Set what = .document.getElementsByName("zip")
what.Item(0).Value = "606061"

Set Search = .document.getElementByClass("btn btn-warning")'Here i need to find the button and click using.
Search.Item(0).click ' I tried to iterate different values up to 4


End With
```

Answer (score 0):

First: Which city should have the zip code 606061?

Second: There is no method `document.getElementByClass`, but `document.getElementsByClassName`.

Third: If you have a INPUT element, then you have also the FORM element with INPUTElement.form. So you can simply submit the form with INPUTElement.form.submit().

```
...
Set what = .document.getElementsByName("zip")
what.Item(0).Value = "60601"

what.Item(0).form.submit

'Set Search = .document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-warning")
'Search.Item(1).Click 
...
```

Greetings

Axel

Answer (score 0):

## **POST requests:**

I inspected doing a zip code search using [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and noticed there is a [POST](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) request made:

[image: Fiddler]

**Note:**

Cookies made need to be set that were already in place because I had navigated from the landing page initially.

In the POST request body there were the folling form parameters (sample shown):

[image: Sample]

I went with a POST request just using the `zip` parameter to the header URL mentioned. I noted that the response was a JSON string.

This string I parsed with JSONConverter into a JSON object (a dictionary). This dictionary object has keys of:

1. listings
2. styleSet
3. serviceProviders
4. Page
5. sellers
6. remainingResults

Each of the keys can be used to further retrieve a collection of dictionaries.

E.g. `Set a = JSON("listings") 'collection of dictionaries`

For the `listings`, which is the subject I will parse below, each dictionary within the collection is a vehicle. And the keys of the dictionary are the listed properties. There is a lot more information here than is immediately visible on the page.

Let's take the first listed vehicle for the test zip I used of `"10001"`.  This returned, when manually selected:

[image: Website listing]

Compare that to the associated `JSON` response info from the `POST` request (this is only a section of all the available listed information for the vehicle!):

[image: JSON response]

---

## **VBA:**

I use JSONConverter as mentioned before to parse the POST response into a dictionary object and then process the "listings" collection. There is a lot of data. I print this initially to the Immediate Window. I also printed to a text file (not included in code). TODO: Investigate how to sensibly deal with the amount of data returned.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetSInfo()
    Dim objHTTP As Object, JSON As Object
    Const ZIP As String = "10001"
    Const URL = "https://www.cargurus.com//Cars/inventorylisting/ajaxFetchSubsetInventoryListing.action?sourceContext=carGurusHomePageModel "
  
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
 
    Dim sBody As String
    sBody = "zip=" & ZIP
  
    With objHTTP
        .SetTimeouts 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000
        .Open "POST", URL, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        On Error Resume Next
        .send (sBody)
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            If .Status = "200" Then
                Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
            Else
                Debug.Print "HTTP " & .Status & " " & .statusText
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Else
            Debug.Print "Error " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Source & " " & Err.Description
            Exit Sub
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Debug.Print TypeName(JSON) 'Dictionary object
    Dim key As Variant
    '   For Each key In JSON.keys
    '       Debug.Print key
    '   Next key
    '
    '   listings
    'styleSet
    'serviceProviders
    'Page
    'sellers
    'remainingResults

    Dim a As Object, i As Long, j As Long
    Set a = JSON("listings")                     'collection of dictionaries
    For i = 1 To a.Count
        For Each key In a(i).keys
            Select Case TypeName(a(i)(key))
            Case "Collection"
                For j = 1 To a(i)(key).Count
                    Debug.Print key & " " & a(i)(key)(j)
                Next j
            Case Else
                Debug.Print key & " " & a(i)(key)
            End Select
        Next key
    Next i
End Sub
```

---

**References:**

Apart from adding in `JSONConverter.bas` you will need to do VBE > Tools > References > `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`